# SQL server database migration to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sql, migration, server-setup

I want to migrate **products**, **categories**, **customers** , **product reviews** and product **related products**, videos etc from sql server database engine to Magento 2. Can anyone help me how to migrate those data?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution for migration:

- Using Rest Api create import data from SQL.
  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html
- Second rewrite some code sciprt  whick connect SQL server and import
  then to Magento

Answer (score 0):

Using REST API will not work for categories since the IDs can not be commited. 
So you need to use the Magento migration tool or 3rd Party software if you want to migrate from M1 to M2. If you have same Version on both sides you can use SQL migration tools or PHPMYADMIN and export / import raw SQL.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html